# File not found exception when writing away file in java (android)

Tags: java, android, file, bitmap, filenotfoundexception

I have a problem saving a file in android, the `FileOutputStream` keeps falling back to a `FileNotFoundException` and thus won't write the file to the external storage.

Yes I do have permission set in the manifest:

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
```

I've added the code below of the function, can someone explain to me what is going wrong, if it is that it is trying to overwrite an existing file, is there a way to replace that file (the name needs to be static)?

(tips on making the code look nicer are welcome as well)

```
Bitmap savebitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawView.getDrawingCache());
File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Android/data/"+getApplicationContext().getPackageName()+"/Files");

if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()){
    mediaStorageDir.mkdir();
}

File pictureFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Android/data/"+getApplicationContext().getPackageName()+"/Files"+File.separator+"Tempsave.png");

try {
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
    savebitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();

}
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
catch (IOException e) {}
```

Kudos to Guillaume and theV0ID for leading me to the most efficient correct answer.
Below is the example code editted to the working version.

```
Bitmap savebitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawView.getDrawingCache());

File pictureFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Android/data/"+getApplicationContext().getPackageName()+"/Files"+File.separator+"Tempsave.png");

pictureFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();

try {
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
    savebitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
catch (IOException e) {}
```

Comment: Please create minimal example to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @theV0ID How do you mean create a minimal example? Reduce the code so only the writing parts remain? Also if it helps trying to load the file gives the error the file/folder does not exist.

Comment: I mean you should remove the part of the code that is clearly irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @theV0ID I have removed everything that has nothing to do with the fileoutputstream as requested

Comment: This is not a minimal example. You still have tons of code that is unrelated. The bitmap compression is clearly unrelated, also you could simplify your paths.

But well, have you checked the return value of `mediaStorageDir.mkdir()`? If must be true `true`. If it is not, the actual problem is somewhere before.

Have you checked whether the `mediaStorageDir` is computed properly? You could view in the debugger or print `mediaStorageDir.toString()` to log cat.

Comment: Here is explained what a minimal example is: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this :

```
File pictureFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Android/data/"+getApplicationContext().getPackageName()+"/Files"+ File.separator + "Tempsave.png");

pictureFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
```

You need to create the file directories if they don't exist. If not the `FileOutputStream` will throw a `FileNotFoundException`

Comment: This did indeed work, for some reason I expected the fileoutputstream to create it by itself, thank you very much

Comment: This is wrong. `FileOutputStream` will create the file if it doesn't exist. It will not if and only if it cannot be created, as [documented here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream%28java.io.File%29) The point is that the **directory** needs to be created.

Comment: @theV0ID Indeed the only thing that was necessary was the pictureFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();